# Is it possible to update KEY_COLUMN_USAGE table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, constraints, information-schema

After renaming a table, I have noticed that some constraints still have the old name for REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE. Is it possible to change that field on some rows or one have to drop those constraints?

Answer (score 1):

This is a system view; it cannot be updated.

---

Possible reason of this behavior (when information_schema is not updated) is that table can be opened, e.g. there is an open cursor/reader on this table. Close this table firstly, or just run [FLUSH TABLES table_name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html).

View opened tables, check `In_use` column -

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES;
```